# How to disable the NotImplementedException for the auto-implemented property?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm having trouble with C# auto implementing the 'NotImplementedException' to the auto-implemented properties whenever I generated them.

This is the interface class :

```
public interface IPerson
{
    string Name {get;set;}
    int Age {get; set;}
    char Gender {get; set;}
    string Email {get;set;}
    string Address {get;set;}
}
```

This is the derived class. It's auto-implementing 'NotImplementedException' method whenever I tried to implement the interface to the derived class.

```
public class Student : IPerson
{
    public Student()
    {

    }

    public string Name { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    public int Age { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    public char Gender { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    public string Email { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    public string Address { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}
```

Is there a way to make that the accessor methods in Student class is not auto-implemented with 'NotImplementedException' when I implement and generated the members from the IPerson interface ?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio or VS Code are you using?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2022 community. I've also tried it in VS code and it's also the same. Is it the C# 10 feature or something related with the IDE ?

Comment: Its how your IDE works.

Comment: May I know whether your issue have been solved or not? If the answer can solve your problem, you could click '✔' to mark it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Selecting `prefer auto properties` will implement properties in interfaces with just `get` or `set` instead of throwing `NotImplementedException`s

This is what the setting looks like in VS 2022

[image]